# Basis of tensor product over non-commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, tensor-products, abelian-groups

Let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules, where  $R$ is a ring, and let $M\otimes_R N$ be the tensor product over $R$. If $R$ is commutative, then the basis of $M\otimes_R N$ is the set
$$
\{ m\otimes_R n :m\in B_M,\ n\in B_N \},
$$
where $B_M$ and $B_N$ are bases of $M$ and $N$, respectively. Is the same true if $R$ is non-commutative?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful, you are probably aware but in general modules do not have any basis.

Also, when $R$ is not commutative you cannot take the tensor product as easily: the tensor product $M\otimes_R N$ only exists when $M$ is a *right* module and $N$ is a *left* module, and in that case $M\otimes_R N$ is *not* an $R$-module, but only an abelian group.

But that being said, if $M$ is a free $R$-module with basis $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ and $N$ is a free left $R$-module with basis $(f_j)_{j\in J}$, then $M\otimes_R N$ is isomorphic to $R^{\oplus I\times J}$ as an abelian group.

Of course any free right module can be seen as a bimodule, but that structure depends on the choice of basis, so it is not canonical. Therefore, although $R^{\oplus I}\otimes R^{\oplus J}\simeq R^{\oplus I\times J}$ canonically as an $R$-$R$-bimodule, if $M$ and $N$ are just abstractly free (with no distinguished choice of basis), we only get a non-canonical isomorphism of abelian groups with $R^{\oplus I\times J}$.

Comment: If $M$ is an $(S,R)$-bimodule, or $N$ is an $(R,S)$-bimodule, then $M \otimes_{R} N$ is a left or right $S$-module respectively. Could any free right or left $R$-module be made into an $(R,R)$-bimodule?

Comment: @freakish You are right, what I wrote was not what I meant. I corrected my answer.